# Is null in catch block required?

Tags: java

```
A a = null;
try {
  a = setA(); // set A throws exception
} catch (AException e) {
  a = null;
}
```

In the code above, do I need use `a = null` in the catch block to ensure that `a` is null if an exception occurs?

Comment: No, it does nothing useful.

Comment: It is better to move `A a` inside the try/catch block as it cannot have a useful value if an Exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the exception was thrown BEFORE the assignment in any case, i assume, that a will always be null here...

Answer (score 2):

If a method returning a value (in this case an object of class `A`) throws and exception, then it never returns a value.

As the line assigning a value to `a` is in this case said method, a never gets a value so `null` remains as the variable's value.